# How to detect when user pastes something when application is running in the background?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, androidx, broadcast

I am trying to detect when a user pastes something outside of my application while my app is running in the background. Specifically, when they hold down and hit the paste button I need to retrieve that action.

Do any of you know how to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible anymore due to privacy and security concerns.

From Google: [Privacy Changes on Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#clipboard-data):

**Limited access to clipboard data**

Unless your app is the default input method editor (IME) or is the app that currently has focus, your app cannot access clipboard data on Android 10 or higher.

Comment: Thank you for the answer that explains why I can't receive a paste action.